# How to stop main PHP script until a child process terminates?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP.

I am trying to write a PHP script which will take a source code (say "test.c"),it will compile the code and run that code.While running the executable ("test.c -> test") , it will take input from other file and give output to other file.Then i will read from the output file.

I have compiled ("gcc -g test.c -o test") and run ("./test") the file by creating a process using "proc_open()" in PHP.Earlier i was facing a problem that my main PHP script was running without waiting for the termination of the child process (an executable will be created and i want that main PHP should run further only when executable has been created.). As i said i want to wait main PHP script until child process terminates , so i searched on Google and found a solution using "pcntl_wait()" but now problem is that when i use "pcntl_wait()", script after the "pcntl_wait()" is not running.I am unable to figure out the problem.

**NOW MY QUESTION IS THAT IS THERE IS ANY METHOD THROUGH WHICH WE CAN MAKE MAIN PHP SCRIPT TO WAIT UNTIL THE CHILD PROCESS TERMINATES?**

If anyone is interested to see how i used  "pcntl_wait()" then i will be thankful for her/him . Here is a part of my code :

```
         $cwd = "/code/";

chmod("/code/test.c",0777);

switch($xtension)
{
    case "c"    :   $cmd = "gcc -g test.c -o test -lm ";
                break;
    case "cpp"  :   $cmd = "g++ -g test.cpp -o test";
                break;
    case "java" :   $cmd = "javac test.java";
}



$descriptors = array(
    2 => array("pipe","w")
);


$process = proc_open($cmd,$descriptors,$pipes,$code);



if(is_resource($process))
{
    $status = proc_get_status($process);
    $pid = $status ["pid"];

    echo getmypid()."<br />";


    echo $pid;

    if(pcntl_waitpid($pid,$child_status) == -1)
    {
        fclose($pipes[2]);

        proc_close($process);
        exit("Sorry!Unable to compile the source_file.\n");


    }
       **/*AFTER IT NOTHING IS RUNNING*/**      


    while(!file_exists("/code/test"))
    {

        proc_close($process);
       echo stream_get_contents($pipes[2]),"\n";
       fclose($pipes[2]);                   

        exit("Sorry!Unable to compile the source_file.\n");
    }

    echo "Compiled Successfully!\n";
    echo "Running test cases...\n";

    fclose($pipes[2]);

    proc_close($process);

}
else
{
    exit("Sorry!Unable to compile the source_file.\n");
}
```